# Angular $timeouts Slow on Mobile Safari

Tags: angularjs, mobile-safari

I have an Angular word game that's perfectly fast from a desktop browser.  But it's got some painfully slow transitions, dialogs, etc., when running on mobile Safari.

I'm developing a theory that there is a greater cost to using $timeout when running on mobile Safari; I don't know why this would be, necessarily.  Is that a known issue with using $timeout?

Comment: I guess probably it is not the timeouts, the animations are causing this. You would need to get hardware accelerations using 3d transforms. I had issues even with large resolution image as well. Just as a test apply `* { transform: translateZ(0);}` everything will get screwed up and most probably you should see better response (_this is just to confirm that your issue can be resolved with bringing GPU into play_).. Point with that is that processors in the devices (esp old ones) are not powerful enough, so mostly you would need to get GPU into play.

Comment: $timeout is pretty much a shortcut for window.setTimeout. SetTimeout is not something that will cause issues on Mobile Safari, but as it executes a function later, there is no garantee it will be executed right when you want (it will be delayed if the JS engine is busy doing something else before getting to check the event loop). So, what happens is the JS engine on Mobile Safari is busy on something else, and that is why your timeout seems to act weird.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to run $apply on scope after each $timeout? If not, use it with additional parameter - false at the end - it will stop $timeout from running $apply at the end:

```
$timeout(function () {
    // your code here
}, 1234, false);
```

But if you creating some sort of animation, consider using `requestAnimationFrame()` - it's better for animation than timeout (and you can allways fallback to timeout when browser doesn't support it). [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) on MDN.